# npm install @material-ui/core got error: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...X1F+dSMvv9bUwJSg+lOUX'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\WR-022\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-19T15_48_14_800Z-debug.log
```

debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\WR-022\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@material-ui/core'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose npm-session c306ec592b524249
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui%2fcore 1376ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @material-ui/core@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...X1F+dSMvv9bUwJSg+lOUX'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4080ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...X1F+dSMvv9bUwJSg+lOUX'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Users\WR-022\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Users\WR-022\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
12 verbose cwd E:\corporate-new-ui
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\WR-022\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@material-ui/core"
15 verbose node v12.13.1
16 verbose npm  v6.13.4
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...X1F+dSMvv9bUwJSg+lOUX'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: update react and react-dom to the latest version`npm install --save react@latest` then   `npm install --save react-dom@latest` then try again with `npm install @material-ui/core`

Comment: I tried it but that didn't help. the problem still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

See this https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072#issuecomment-345555468
I hope that solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap @material-ui/core with ' :

```
    npm install '@material-ui/core'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I also went to the exact same problem using the NPM , which resulted in getting the same error as above .
So instead of NPM i tried to use the yarn and it worked

Please try the following command

```
yarn add @material-ui/core
```